# Sum duration of time by group and only sum overlap if group members>1

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a problem of coming up with a DAX measure to sum up unavailable time due to maintenance per unit and per site.
My dataset has unit identifiers, site identifiers, start and end of maintenance timestamp (date time format). Most sites have one unit but some can have 2 or 3 or more.

I need to calculate amount of time each unit and each site was unavailable due to maintenance.

With units is straightforward: Unavailable time per unit equals the sum of the differences of all end timestamps and start timestamps per unit.
With sites I have a problem. Simple sum is not the right answer because if at least one unit at the site is not under maintenance the site is okay.

If site has one unit - if its maintained - that site is unavailable. If site has 2 or 3 or more units, it is unavailable only for the time where all the units on the site are maintained in the same time.

So I need help coming up with a query that will sum up duration of maintenance times per site if there is one unit on the site and sum up only overlapping duration when all units are maintained if there is multiple units on site.

Is that is even possible could you please point me towards the solution. Ive been playing with this for hours now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add an example of your dataset?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhr6viv4ro30hwm/Data.xlsb?dl=0

Comment: I have come up with an idea, but it kills my machine (ryzen 9 16core, 64gb ram) so probably not the greatest of solutions.

Comment: I was thinking of generating a series of minutes from start date to end date across each site, then count the number of machines where start date + minute_X that were under maintenance. Then filter where count = total machines per site, and add up the minutes. It works if I select one day, but otherwise it kills the machine.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but Im afraid of scalability. This is one month data. What if later needs to be multiple months? I was hoping powerquery has time intelligence capabilities to avoid expanding the dataset tremendously such as adding minute by minute records. And then group by site and filter out anything that is not an overlap between all machines on the site. I just dont have the proper level skill to implement that at this stage :(

Comment: And thank you for your comments and effort Joao. You made me think it through from different perspective. I appreciate it.